# Character string output when I exceeds the limit

Tags: c, loops, initialization, reverse, c-strings

Here I'm using two string

```
char str[5], rev[5];
```

Initially I was trying to performe reverse of a string and it was successful.

While I'm printing the characters of `rev` string  I mistakenly exceed the limit of string, but still string `rev` printing the characters of it.

First I accessed 6 elements from string, in that last element was   blank . This is OKAY because last character having **'\0'**.

But when I try to access more than **6** elements it's printing the character which are belong to given string ( in my case it is `rev`) and some are characters.

**This is my code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[5] = "Hello";
    char rev[5];
    int i = -1, j = 0;
    while(str[++i] != '\0');
    while(i >= 0)
    {
        rev[j++] = str[--i];
    }
    printf("\n i = %d ", i);
    printf("\n j = %d \n\n ", j);

    rev[--j] = '\0';

    printf("%s is reversed string \n ", rev);

    for(int k = -5; k <= 15; k++)
    {
        printf("\n k --> %d = %2c", k, rev[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand how this working

```
$ ./a

 i = -1
 j = 6

 olleH is reversed string

 k --> -5 =  � 
 k --> -4 =  �
 k --> -3 =  �
 k --> -2 =
 k --> -1 =
 k --> 0 =  o   <-  Here is the starting point
 k --> 1 =  l
 k --> 2 =  l
 k --> 3 =  e
 k --> 4 =  H
 k --> 5 =
 k --> 6 =  e    <--|
 k --> 7 =  l    <--|   From where it comes
 k --> 8 =  l    <--|   And how
 k --> 9 =  o    <--|
 k --> 10 =
 k --> 11 =
 k --> 12 =
 k --> 13 =
 k --> 14 =  H    <--|   This one as well
 k --> 15 =  �
```

May be this questios sounds weird**.**

Comment: `char str[5] = "Hello";` doesn't have a `\0`. You made it too small, so `while(str[++i] != '\0');` will run out of bounds and your program therefore has undefined behavior. It should be `char str[6] = "Hello";` or just `char str[] = "Hello";` to let it figure out the proper size itself.

Comment: When you access an array out of bounds, you invoke undefined behavior.  Anything can happen, and it's generally not worth speculating about the actual behavior that you see.

Comment: Note also that `while(str[++i] != '\0');` is not the proper way to get the string length. What happens if the string is `""`? **boom** - out of bounds! Use `strlen(str);` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The array `str` does not contain a string. Its initialization

```
char str[5] = "Hello";
```

is equivalent to

```
char str[5] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
```

That is the array `str` does not contain the terminating zero character `'\0'`.

So starting from this while loop

```
while(str[++i] != '\0');
```

the program invokes undefined behavior.

Also in the next loop

```
while(i >= 0)
{
    rev[j++] = str[--i];
}
```

there is used the expression `str[-1]` when `i` is equal to `0` that also invokes undefined behavior.

You could declare the arrays for example the following way

```
char str[] = "Hello";
char rev[sizeof( str )];
```

And substitute this statement

```
rev[--j] = '\0';
```

for this one

```
rev[j] = '\0';
```

Also this loop

```
for(int k = -5; k <= 15; k++)
{
    printf("\n k --> %d = %2c", k, rev[k]);
}
```

does not make a sense because there are attempts to access memory beyond the defined array. Remove it.

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char str[] = "Hello";
    char rev[sizeof( str )];

    size_t i = 0;
    
    while ( str[i] != '\0' ) i++;
    
    size_t j = 0;
    
    while ( i != 0 )
    {
        rev[j++] = str[--i];
    }
    
    printf( "i = %zu\n", i );
    printf( "j = %zu\n\n", j );

    rev[j] = '\0';
    
    printf( "%s is reversed string\n ", rev );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
i = 0
j = 5

olleH is reversed string
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it is weird :-) You are abusing your code by accessing arrays with negative indexes, which is not a safe things to do. The biggest problem is that you only reserve 5 chars for the Hello string, but you should put at least 6, factoring the \0 terminator char. It all goes downhill from here

When you do things like these, many factors interact, including the compiler, the operating system and more. So, in my case the program gives a different output.

```
 i = -1 
 j = 9 

 �olleH is reversed string 
 
 k --> -5 =  H
 k --> -4 =  e
 k --> -3 =  l
 k --> -2 =  l
 k --> -1 =  o
 k --> 0 =  
 k --> 1 =  �
 k --> 2 =  
 k --> 3 =  o
 k --> 4 =  l
 k --> 5 =  l
 k --> 6 =  e
 k --> 7 =  H
 k --> 8 =  
 k --> 9 =  �
 k --> 10 =  �
 k --> 11 =  /
 k --> 12 =  �
 k --> 13 =  
 k --> 14 =  
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./a.out terminated
 k --> 15 =
```

O